# Ansible Regex Help needed: Unable to grab output and assign to a set_fact variable

Tags: regex, networking, stdout, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I am trying to grab the "CRC Input Error" count and assign it to a variable "crc_count" however, the value of this variable is showing as an empty string instead `("crc_count": "")`. What am I missing here?

Code:

```
- name: Checking CRC Errors on the Interfaces
  nxos_command:
      commands:
              - show interface ethernet 1/1 counters detailed all
  register: crc_output
- debug: var=crc_output.stdout_lines[0][50]
- set_fact: crc_count= "{{ crc_output.stdout_lines[0][50] | regex_search('(\d{0,20}$)') }}"

- debug:
        msg: "{{ crc_count }}"
```

String output that I want to run regex on:

```
"crc_output.stdout_lines[0][50]": "  10.                  Input CRC Errors: = 4272"
```

Output I want to grab:

```
crc_count = "4272"
```

Playbook verbose output:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /ansible/saurasar/nxos.crc.check.yml:19
ok: [ord12-pob-c1u1-dci-1.uspp1.oraclecloud.com] => {
    "crc_output.stdout_lines[0][50]": "  10.                  Input CRC Errors: = 4272"
}

TASK [set_fact] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /ansible/xxxx/nxos.crc.check.yml:20
ok: [cisco.nexus.switch] => {"ansible_facts": {"_raw_params": "\"4272\"", "crc_count": ""}, "changed": false}

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /ansible/xxxxx/nxos.crc.check.yml:22
ok: [cisco.nexus.switch] => {
    "msg": ""
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
<cisco.nexus.switch> : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Your regex requires the number to be at end of line but there is a quote after it.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

```
 - set_fact:
     crc_count: "{{ result.stdout | regex_replace('^.*Input CRC Errors: = (.*)$', '\\1') }}"
```

I tried with your sample and got as below

> ok: [localhost] => {
>       "ansible_facts": {
>           "crc_count": "4272"
>       },
>       "changed": false
>   }

Comment: Please mark and solution as answer and upvote if it was helpful